# Practicality of Add-In Pipeline in C#

Tags: c#, add-in, mef, pipeline, maf

How practical is using the MEF pipeline in your application for a add-in/plug-in environment?

If, for example I want to create a basic reporting base class, then extend the functionality using some kind of add-in setup (like the MEF pipeline), how practical is it to use it in this setup?

I haven't many applications using this model (if someone has a list of commercial software using this I'd be interested to check it out)

Comment: Visual studio uses MEF for add ins ;).

Answer (score 1):

> How practical is using the MEF pipeline in your application for a
>   add-in/plug-in environment?

i use [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) all the way for my loosly coupled applications.

> What is it? The Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) is a composition
>   layer for .NET that improves the flexibility, maintainability and
>   testability of large applications. MEF can be used for third-party
>   plugin extensibility, or it can bring the benefits of a
>   loosely-coupled plugin-like architecture to regular applications.

btw PRSIM can be used with MEF, but there are a lot of other examples in the www.

Comment: can you use multiple add-in types using the one pipeline i.e. if i want add-ins for reporting and add-ins for calculations is this possible?

Comment: you should look at the MEF documentation. and of course you can have multiple add-in([ImportMany] is your friend then)

Comment: thanks.. any clues on my other question regarding the AddInStore class and being able to specify the directories and .dll files of the pipeline?